# Lifting degeneracy in Topological Insulators

Tags: symmetry, topological-insulators

I was reading the review by M.Z. Hasan and C.L. Kane on topological insulators and had a question regarding degeneracy lifting. In the review, they mention that Haldane imagined breaking time reversal symmetry with a magnetic field which is zero on the average but has full lattice symmetry.

At the edges of a topological insulator, we have linearly dispersed protected states forming Dirac cones (in contrast to the gapped band structure in the bulk). These states allow for conductance on surface channels. So why would we want to lift the degeneracy of the Dirac point? Wouldn't this destroy the surface states and just turn it into a standard insulator?